# Writing a program that goes from a number x in base 10 to a vector with the number in base 16 in R

Tags: r, algorithm, hex, radix

```
hexadecimal1 <- function(x) {

y <- integer(0)

   while (x >= 16) {
   r <- x%%16
   x <- x%/%16
   y <- c(r, y)
   if(r==10) { r<- "A"}
   if(r==11) { r<- "B"}
   if(r==12) { r<- "C"}
   if(r==13) { r<- "D"}
   if(r==14) { r<- "E"}
   if(r==15) { r<- "F"}
   } 
y <- c(x, y)
y
}
```

I am supposed to write an algorithm that gives number in hexadecimal in a vector. My current algorithm actually works but displays 10,11,12,13,14,15 instead of A,B,C,D,E,F... 
Any idea how I can make the output be with those letters instead of 10, 11, ...
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you happy to print `1, 2, 3, ....etc` for values less than 10?

Comment: A suggestion for how to solve it yourself: tell a rubber ducky on your desk what each line does to each variable. Pay particular attention to what happens to r AFTER you've set it to a letter inside the while loop. I.e., you've set it to, say, "B". What's the next thing that happens to r?

Comment: Then just move the line `    r <- x%%16` below last `if`. You are not allowing `r` to be evaluated before it is merged in `y`.

Comment: @LakhdarMohamedAmine sort of. See my answer below for a rubber ducky that can both listen and respond.

Comment: @LakhdarMohamedAmine. Stop defacing your questions. If this was homework, then you probably should have been forthright about it.

Answer (score 5):

There's an R function that already does that:

```
> prin_hex <- function(x) print(as.hexmode(x))
> prin_hex(30)
[1] "1e"
> prin_hex <- function(x) print(paste(x, "==", as.hexmode(x)))
> prin_hex(30)
[1] "30 == 1e"
```

You could also leave a numeric value of class-`hexmode` and the `print.hexmode` function would return a character value while letting numeric operations continue to be performed on it.

(There's also an octmode for octal.)

After looking at the code for print.hexmode (which refers us to format.hexmode), we find that the heavy lifting for the `print` (by way of `format`) generics for the hexmode class is being done by

```
 sprintf("%x", <numeric>)

 # e.g.
> sprintf("%x", 20)
[1] "14"
```

Comment: I like `structure(x, class = "hexmode")`, mostly because I have no idea what it's doing.  But I suspect the OP needs to write the actual algorithm, not just get the behavior.

Comment: Hard to tell. Does sound like a homework assignmnet, but maybe the students are allowed to discover hidden features in the R language? There is a set of generic functions (`print` and the numeric operators) that are tailored to the hexmode class. It's  slick way to allow the values to remain ordinary numerics while inheriting some printable features.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of giving you a working algorithm, let me give you a debugging tool:

Change your function to this:

```
hexadecimal1 <- function(x) {
  browser()
  y <- integer(0)

  while (x >= 16) {
    r <- x%%16
    x <- x%/%16
    y <- c(r, y)
    if(r==10) { r<- "A"}
    if(r==11) { r<- "B"}
    if(r==12) { r<- "C"}
    if(r==13) { r<- "D"}
    if(r==14) { r<- "E"}
    if(r==15) { r<- "F"}
  } 
  y <- c(x, y)
  y
}
```

Next, call: `hexadecimal1(31)`

To figure out what to do next, type `help` and then hit Enter.

Here's a hint: type `n` and then hit Enter.

To make it easier, do this in RStudio and keep your eye on the Environment tab in the upper right hand pane.

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
hex <- function(x) {
    if(x==0) return("0")
    if(x<0) return(paste0("-", hex(-x)))

    map <- c(as.character(0:9), LETTERS[1:6])
    res <- c()
    while (x>0) {
        res <- c(map[x %% 16 + 1], res)
        x <- x %/% 16
    }
    return(res)
}
```

Comment: bah. make him do the debugging :p  but yes, this obviously works quite nicely and answers the question he asked. upvoted!

Comment: You can avoid growing `res` by defining `res <- character(ceiling(logb(x, 16))); i <- length(res)`, running the while loop for `i > 0` and using `res[i] <- map[x %% 16 + 1]`.  You'll also need to add `i <- i - 1` to the loop.